# How to check if object is an array of a certain type?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reflection, types

This works fine:

```
var expectedType = typeof(string);
object value = "...";
if (value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(expectedType))
{
     ...
}
```

But how do I check if value is a string array without setting `expectedType` to `typeof(string[])`? I want to do something like:

```
var expectedType = typeof(string);
object value = new[] {"...", "---"};
if (value.GetType().IsArrayOf(expectedType)) // <---
{
     ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to know if the object was declared as a string[]. or if an object[] contains only instances of a certain type?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use [Type.IsArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray.aspx) and [Type.GetElementType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) to check the element type of an array.

```
Type valueType = value.GetType();
if (valueType.IsArray && expectedType.IsAssignableFrom(valueType.GetElementType())
{
 ...
}
```

Beware the [Type.IsAssignableFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx). If you want to check the type for an exact match you should check for equality (`typeA == typeB`). If you want to check if a given type is the type itself or a subclass (or an interface) then you should use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`:

```
typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ExpectedSubclass))
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use **extension methods** (not that you have to but makes it **more readable**):

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsArrayOf<T>(this Type type)
    {
         return type == typeof (T[]);
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string[0].GetType().IsArrayOf<string>());
```

Answer (score 7):

```
value.GetType().GetElementType() == typeof(string)
```

as an added bonus (but I'm not 100% sure. This is the code I use...)

```
var ienum = value.GetType().GetInterface("IEnumerable`1");

if (ienum != null) {
    var baseTypeForIEnum = ienum.GetGenericArguments()[0]
}
```

with this you can look for List, IEnumerable... and get the T.

Answer (score 7):

The neatest and securest way to do it that found is using `MakeArrayType`:

```
var expectedType = typeof(string);
object value = new[] {"...", "---"};
if (value.GetType() == expectedType.MakeArrayType())
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another sample,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type type = typeof(string[]);
        // string[], int[], char[], List<MyData>, IList<MyData>, IEnumarable<MyData>  =====> console write "True",
        // string, int, MyData etc ==== does not write 
        
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
        {
            Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }
        
        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }       
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Do you actually need to know the type of the array? Or do you only need the elements to be of a certain type?

If the latter, you can simply filter only the elements that match what you want:

```
string[] strings = array.OfType<string>();
```

Answer (score -7):

```
if(objVal.GetType().Name == "Object[]")
```

true for array