# Casting object to IEnumerable of a generic type stored in a variable

Tags: c#, generics, casting, .net-3.5, system.reflection

I'm receiving an array via a FieldInfo variable. In reality, it can be a string[] and sometimes it can be CustomObject[], I suppose I should expect IEnumerable in the future too.

Since it's not the only parsable object, first I need to check if it's an IEnumerable:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
```

Then [I get type type of object stored in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274865/how-to-check-if-object-is-an-array-of-a-certain-type):

```
var elementType = field.FieldType.GetElementType();
```

But since I need to make some operations on it I need to cast

```
var listAsObject = field.GetValue(this);
```

to

```
IEnumerable<elementType>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do that, but if there are only two possible cases then you can do `if(elementType == typeof(string)) { var strings = (IEnumerable<string>)field.GetValue(this); }` and similarly for the `CustomObject` case.

Comment: It appears that you're right, Lee. My dilemma now is whether to close this question or leave it, because some day c# will make that possible?

Comment: Can you do `listAsObject.Cast<elementType>.theOperationIWant()`?

Comment: No. I'm getting a "The type or namespace name elementType could not be found".